# How do I stop DHCP to request address for a static interface?

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip-address, ubuntu-20.10

I have a Raspberry PI 4 running Ubuntu 21.10 with a static ip-address on eth0. Despite that, I keep getting a secondary 'dynamic' DHCP address on on it.

netplan

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.10/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          search: [lan]
          addresses: [192.168.0.12]
```

ip addr show

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:da:df:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/23 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.225/23 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 68727sec preferred_lft 68727sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:feda:df55/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Even if I delete that interface, it keeps coming back after a few minutes. I have another PI with the "same" configuration and it doesn't have this problem.
I also have the **/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg** per instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the word `false` instead of `no` on your `dhcp4` entry to netplan?

Comment: That didn't work either. But I noticed that (not surprising) it makes a new DHCP request every time I run 'netplan apply'

Comment: This is really interesting.  I use that directive in Netplan for a few Ubuntu 18 virtual machines and don't see this behavior.  Very interesting.  Wondering if this is a nuance on Pi.  I have some spare Pi SBCs around, I may tinker with this.

Comment: I have 3 PIs, all same model, all same OS and version, all updated and only one of them does this. I've been trying to fix this for a few days now and every time I find some network related clue, it turns out to be identical on all 3 of them. Strange is putting it mildly. One is running a custom weather program, one is running pi-hole and the one with the problem is running IRedMail, Radicale and a custom shopping program.